# Is There any Geometric Intuition for the Integral Substitution Rule?

Tags: calculus, geometry, intuition

Is there any geometric intuition for the integral substitution rule?

I understand  how to use it and I understand why it works mathematically, I'm just wondering whether or not there is a geometric way of representing it which would provide some visual intuition.

Comment: What's your understanding of why it works mathematically?

Comment: @littleO we define $x$ as the output of a function $g(u)$, find that $dx = g'(u) \, du$, recalculate the boundaries and insert everything into a new integral.

Comment: Yes. When $u$ is transformed into $x$ short segments of length $du$ are transformed into segments scaled by the factor close to $g'(u)$. This becomes exact in the limit when $g(u)$ can be identified with its tangent at $u$. In the integral you add up values weighed by these lengths and take the limit. Since the weights are the same in the limit so are the integrals.